# If I need different answer choices based on question number, can that be automated

Tags: environments, conditionals, counters, enumitem

I asked a question relating to this but I did not have a working example. Here is the original post [is-there-a-way-to-alternate-answer-choices-based-on-the-question-number-act-st](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506930/is-there-a-way-to-alternate-answer-choices-based-on-the-question-number-act-st) .  To summarize I want to make answer choices that have a different starting number depending if the question is even or odd.  I think I need to make an environment and set up conditional statements that refer to the counter of the question, but I have not found similar examples.

Thank you for reading!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitems}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Passage I}
\begin{multicols}{2}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Intro paragraph
Intro paragraph place holder before starting questions
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question 1
    \begin{enumerate}[A.]
        \item Choice A
        \item Choice B
        \item Choice C
        \item Choice D
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Question 2
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start = 6]
        \item Choice F
        \item Choice G
        \item Choice H
        \skipitems{1}
        \item Choice J
    \end{enumerate}
        \item Question 3
    \begin{enumerate}[A.]
        \item Choice A
        \item Choice B
        \item Choice C
        \item Choice D
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Question 4
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start = 6]
        \item Choice F
        \item Choice G
        \item Choice H
        \skipitems{1}
        \item Choice J
    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could have edited the existing question. If this post is essentially an extended duplicate of that, could you delete the earlier question to get it off the list of unanswered questions, thanks.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification.  I did not want to complete redo the original post, because it could make the comments invalid.  I will delete the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitems}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\startval{\ifodd\value{enumi} 1 \else 6 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Passage I}
\begin{multicols}{2}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Intro paragraph
Intro paragraph place holder before starting questions
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question 1
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start=\startval]
        \item Choice A
        \item Choice B
        \item Choice C
        \item Choice D
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Question 2
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start=\startval]
        \item Choice F
        \item Choice G
        \item Choice H
        \skipitems{1}
        \item Choice J
    \end{enumerate}
        \item Question 3
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start=\startval]
        \item Choice A
        \item Choice B
        \item Choice C
        \item Choice D
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Question 4
    \begin{enumerate}[A., start=\startval]
        \item Choice F
        \item Choice G
        \item Choice H
        \skipitems{1}
        \item Choice J
    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: David, thank you for your response.  My startval command does not alternate answer choices, so I think there is an issue with using the enumctr.  My hypothesis is that enumctr is 0, since it is the beginning of the enumerate. Would it be possible to edit your command, to have it based on the first level enumerator?  Something like \newcommand\startval{\ifodd\value\@enumi 1 \else 6 \fi}   I tried this, but it results in undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @DavidLord the example document as posted in this answer alternates doesn't it?

Comment: Yay! I got it! 
I changed it to \newcommand\startval{\ifodd\value{enumi} 1 \else 6 \fi} and that works as I hope it would.   Thank you!

Comment: To answer your question, it did not alternate in my document.  It made the Choices all start with F whether the question number was even or odd.

Comment: @DavidLord sorry last minute change broke it, I fixed the post to match your comment above.

Comment: Looks good!  Also I am reading an ifthen document written by you.  Also I tried typing @DavidCarlisle and it does not show up